# C# Spawn new thread and then wait

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am very inexperienced using multi-threading techniques, but here is what I have tried:

```
Thread thread = null;

for (int minute = 0; minute < 60; minute++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(60000);

    if (thread != null)
    {
        while (thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running) { }
    }

    thread = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        // Do stuff during the next minute whilst the main thread is sleeping.
    });
    thread.Start();
}
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to have a thread running and doing work whilst the main thread sleeps, but I am unsure why the above code doesn't work. What happens is that following the first loop (after starting the thread) the ThreadState doesn't seem to change from "Running". I am also curious as to whether there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Anyone know the problem?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, but perhaps it isn't clear what I am trying to achieve. I want to run the code given in the thread delegate whilst the main thread sleeps for one minute, but if the new thread doesn't complete during this minute then the main thread will wait for it to finish before creating another new thread. This is required so that the minute count is as close to a real minute as possible.

Comment: Hmmm .. still not getting it. What You're saying is that the main thread should wait until the spawned thread finished, but at least one minute? Is that right?

Comment: Here's how the process should go: On the first iteration of the for loop the main thread will wait for 1 minute, after this, it will create a new thread to execute a task in parallel. Having started this new thread it then iterates a second time, the main thread sleeps for 1 minute, and then if the parallel task [strangely] hasn't finished its job during that minute, it will wait for it to do so. Once the parallel task has finished, it will then create a new thread, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a better way to wait for a thread to end.

Comment: There was actually a problem in my code which caused the parallel code to run indefinitely. I implemented this, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .Net 4, I'd recommend taking a look at the [Task Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx).  It makes working with multithreading much easier/straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Task` class you can do this.

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    // Do stuff here.
  });

task.Wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Sleep(60000) is executed on the thread that calls it, in this case the main thread. Which is fine, but the "thread" doesn't know how long it has been running for and doesn't know when to actually stop. You need to have an object tell "thread" that it has been running for 60 seconds.

```
Thread thread = null;

for (int minute = 0; minute < 60; minute++)
{
    if (thread != null)
    {
        while (thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running) { }
    }

    thread = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        try
        {
            // Do stuff during the next minute whilst the main thread is sleeping.
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
        {
        }
    });
    thread.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
    thread.Abort();
}
```

This should achieve what you want but isn't really the most elegant way of stopping a thread. A thread should really be ended using callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

What you may be looking for is something more like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        // Something that takes up to an hour
    });
thread.Start();

for (int minute = 0; minute < 60; minute++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
    if (thread.IsAlive)
        Console.WriteLine("Still going after {0} minute(s).", minute);
    else
        break; // Finished early!
}

// Check if it's still running
if (thread.IsAlive)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Didn't finish after an hour, something may have screwed up!");
    thread.Abort();
}
```

If this is what you're looking for, I'd take a look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.